# Attribute not found on first load of android studio 3.5

Tags: android

Trying to follow along with a udacity course and on first load of android studio 3.5 in a new activity. When I open res --> layout --> activite_main.xml I get multiple errors. Attribute android:layout_height(or width or tools) is not allowed here. Also getting Element TextView is not allowed here. Have done nothing to this project aside from open the res file.

Tried looking up the issue but haven't had any luck.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for putting this as an answer as I do not have the rep to comment but.

Have you tried going to the AndroidManifest.xml and checking that the following lines exist?

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Should be just before the tag

```
</application>
```

This is what your basic manifest should look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.defined.name">

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_wms"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_wms_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and then in the build.Gradle(module: app) these lines should exist

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion '//should match targetSdkVersion'
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.defined.name"
        multiDexEnabled true
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    }
```

Comment: I have not as i'm still very new to this. I will check on that I did a fresh install of android stupid also I just found out I never had java installed but had JDK so maybe it was because I didn't have java installed in the first place. I will update if I find a solution.

Comment: Okay I Just checked and that is also full of errors have about 6. attribute allowbackup, icon, roundicon, supportsrtl, theme not allowed and unsolved class MainActivity.

Comment: I edited to include all necessary data you will need to compile a basic application. If it still doesn't work, May I suggest closing and re-opening android studio, then starting a new project
File -> New -> New Project... -> Empty Activity

Comment: There was a gradle load that needed to be done once I start a new project that wouldn't happen due to my bad internet (Live in the arctic) once that finally went through all the errors disappeared. Guess that was the problem, so simple. Thanks for the help though!